# City Jetta Passenger Windows Unresponsive

Tags: vw, car, power-windows

I have a 2008 VW City Jetta. About a month ago, I had a remote car starter installed - big mistake. Upon installation, all passenger automatic windows were no longer responsive from either the driver side control panel or from each of the individual passenger window button.

The company who installed the remote starter has gone great lengths to figure out the problem , but to no avail.

Here are some of the things they tried:

- restarted car controls by disconnecting battery ... This allows all passenger windows to move up and down from each individual bottom... However after about 10 minutes it stops working.
- changed the driver side motor (didn't fix the problem)
- changed the driver side control panel (didn't fix the problem)
- checked the fuse (no issues)

The driver side control panel works for the driver side window (so the motor is in working order), it can lock all doors, and move all side mirrors.

When the car is running off battery and I click the driver side window button, the interior lights will dim (the window will go up / down). When I click the passenger window buttons either from the driver side control panel or each individual button, the interior lights do not dim.

So there's no power to those controls.

Any idea what the issue is???

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Without pointing out the oblivious the best thing to do would be to start from the battery and work your way to each control with a multi-meter and find out exactly what's causing it, if the controls aren't getting power then chances are it's either a fuse, something wired up wrong or a burnt out wire(less likely because the fuse would just blow)